# got incorrect mapping from dictionary to array in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I intend to merge two data frames, Chicago crime and Redfin real estate data, but Redfin data was collected by neighborhood in Chicago, while crime data were collected by community area. To do so, I found [neighborhood map](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/81a2b894a3ef48ba4d675f8ffcfe5584) in Chicago and I am kinda figured out how to assign neighborhood to the community area. the structure of two dataframe is a bit different, so I did a few step manipulation on that. here are the details about my attempt:

**example data snippet**

here is the public gist where I can view the [example data snippet](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/e43bde784cc1f63e1c2f3611ecbef343).

here is the [neighborhood mapping](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/81a2b894a3ef48ba4d675f8ffcfe5584) that I collected from the online source.

**my solution**

here is my first mapping solution:

```
code_pairs_neighborhoods = [[p[0], p[1]] for p in [pair.strip().split('\t') for pair in neighborhood_Map.strip().split('\n')]]
neighborhood_name_dic = {k[0]:k[1] for k in code_pairs_neighborhoods} #neighborhood -> community area

chicago_crime['neighborhood'] = chicago_crime['community_name'].map(neighborhood_name_dic)
Redfin['neighborhood'] = Redfin['Region'].map(neighborhood_name_dic)

final_df= pd.merge(chicago_crime, chicago_crime, on='neighborhood')
```

but this solution didn't find correct mapping and `neighborhood` becomes NAN, which is wrong.

**second mapping attempt**:

without using neighborhood mapping, I intuitively come up this solution for mapping:

```
chicago_crime['community_name']=[[y.split() for y in x] for x in chicago_crime['community_name']]
Redfin['Region']= [[j.split() for j in i] for i in Redfin['Region']]

idx, datavalue = [], []
for i,dv in enumerate(chicago_crime['community_name']):
    for d in dv:
        if d in Redfin['Region'][i]:   
            if i not in idx:
                idx.append(i)
                datavalue.append(d)

chicago_crime['merge_ref'] = datavalue
Redfin['merge_ref'] = datavalue

final_df= pd.merge(chicago_crime[['community_area','community_name','merge_ref']], Redfin, on='merge_ref')
```

but this solution gave me error: `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`, `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`.

how can I make this work? based on [neighborhood mapping](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/81a2b894a3ef48ba4d675f8ffcfe5584), how can I get correct mapping both for Redfin data and chicago crime data? Any idea to make this mapping correct and get right merged dataframe? any thought? thanks in advance.

**update**:

I put all of my solution including dataset on this github repository [all solution and data on github](https://github.com/julaiti/Redfin_solution.git)

Comment: We will need more information to help you, e.g. what is `neighborhood_Map`, how do you read in the data that you posted (e.g. does `chicago_crime` come from `read_csv`?), what are you trying to achieve with all these `split()`'s ? Perhaps you could give us 2-3 rows of input and your desired output?

Comment: @Asmus would you able to open an external link, so I could share all of my solution, data that I used? Thank you

Comment: Couldn't you include your main code in the Github that you linked to (or is this not your github repo?)? Also, I think editing your question so that it includes the how you created `Redfin`, `chicago_crime`, `neighborhood_Map`, and so on, would be extremely helpful

Comment: @Asmus I created [github repos](https://github.com/julaiti/Redfin_solution.git) for this problem including my solution and dataset. any idea?

Comment: @Asmus I got `Redfin` data by using the solution from this post [how can I get Redfin dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883846/any-quick-way-to-get-correct-aggregation-output-for-time-series-data-using-panda/55885193#55885193). Any further help?

Comment: I've updated my answer and tried to incorporate the other DataFrame, see below.

Comment: @Asmus I want to do aggregation for `house_df` before merging, I've used the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883846/any-quick-way-to-get-correct-aggregation-output-for-time-series-data-using-panda/55885193#55885193). can you point me out?

Comment: You should be able to just do `new_df['neighborhood']=new_df['Region'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('Chicago, IL - '))` with the `new_df` from the other post (to get "clean" neighborhood names) and then continue to do the merge which I posted?

Comment: Oh, that's easy to answer: I have no idea! :-)

Comment: @Asmus as the continuation of your updated solution, can we still use same join `pd.merge(chicago_crime, house_df, left_on='neighborhood', right_on='neighborhood')` ? are we going to update neiborhood map by inserting this `added = list(sorted(set2 - set1))` ? could you complete your soluton? thank you very much for your good work.

Comment: have you looked at the article I linked to (at the very bottom of my answer) and decided on which type of join you need? You should be able to "play around" with the different merges and see what suits you best!

Comment: @Asmus do I need to add `added = list(sorted(set2 - set1))` neighborhood mapping before merging, for me using inner join works fine. can you complete your answer, so I could accept your nice solution, thanks again for the help.

Comment: You can still the use the `pd.merge(…)` I had posted before, just make sure you're running the cleanup in the top code box of **Update2** *before* the merge. The lower code box was only to demonstrate that you'll update with 46 entries on your inner join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's what I found:

- there is a unicode character in the first line of `neighborhood_Map` that you probably want to remove: `Cabrini\xe2\x80\x93Green'`-> `Cabrini Green`
- switch the key and value in `neighborhood_name_dic` around, since you want to map the existing 'Rogers Park' to the neighborhood 'East Rogers Park', like so:

  `neighborhood_name_dic = {k[1]:k[0] for k in code_pairs_neighborhoods}`

We still don't know from your code how your reading in your [Redfin data](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/e43bde784cc1f63e1c2f3611ecbef343#file-redfin-data), but I presume you'll have to remove the `Chicago, IL -` part in the `Region` column somewhere, before you can merge?

---

**Update:** So I think I managed to understand your code (*again, please try to clean up these things a bit before posting*), and I think that `Redfin` is equal to `house_df` there. So instead of the line that says:

```
house_df=house_df.set_index('Region',drop=False)
```

I would suggest to create a neighbourhood column:

```
house_df['neighborhood'] = house_df['Region'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('Chicago, IL - '))
```

and then you can merge on:

```
crime_finalDF = pd.merge(chicago_crime, house_df, left_on='neighborhood', right_on='neighborhood')
```

To test it, try:

```
mask=(crime_finalDF['neighborhood']==u'Sheridan Park')
print(crime_finalDF[['robbery','neighborhood', u'2018-06-01 00:00:00']][mask])
```

which yields:

```
   robbery   neighborhood  2018-06-01 00:00:00
0    140.0  Sheridan Park                239.0
1    122.0  Sheridan Park                239.0
2    102.0  Sheridan Park                239.0
3    113.0  Sheridan Park                239.0
4    139.0  Sheridan Park                239.0
```

so a successful join of both datasets (I think).

**Update 2**, regarding the success of the `merge()`.

This is how I read in and cleaned up your `xlsx` file:

```py
house_df = pd.read_excel("./real_eastate_data_main.xlsx",)
house_df.replace({'-': None})
house_df.columns=house_df.columns.astype(str)

house_df = house_df[house_df['Region'] != 'Chicago, IL']
house_df = house_df[house_df['Region'] != 'Chicago, IL metro area']

house_df['neighborhood'] = house_df['Region'].str.split(' - ')## note the surrounding spaces
house_df['neighborhood'] = house_df['neighborhood'].map(lambda x: list(x)[-1])

chicago_crime['neighborhood'] = chicago_crime['community_name'].map(neighborhood_name_dic)

## Lakeview and Humboldt park not defined in neighborhood_name_dic
# print( chicago_crime[['community_name','neighborhood']][pd.isnull(chicago_crime['neighborhood'])] )
chicago_crime = chicago_crime[~pd.isnull(chicago_crime['neighborhood'])] ## remove them
```

Now we turn to finding all unique neighborhoods in both df's

```py
cc=sorted(chicago_crime['neighborhood'].unique())
ho=sorted(house_df['neighborhood'].unique())

print(30*u"-"+u" chicago_crime: "+30*u"-")
print(len(cc),cc)
print(30*u"-"+u" house_df: "+30*u"-")
print(len(ho),ho)
print(60*"-")
# print('\n'.join(cc))

set1 = set(cc)
set2 = set(ho)

missing = list(sorted(set1 - set2))
added = list(sorted(set2 - set1))

print('These {0} are missing in house_df: {1}'.format(len(missing),missing))
print(60*"-")

print('These {0} are only in house_df: {1}'.format(len(added),added))
```

Which reveals that **29 are missing in house_df** (e.g. 'East Pilsen') and **132 are found only within house_df** (e.g. 'Albany Park'), i.e. we can "inner join" only 46 entries.

Now *you have to decide how you want to continue*, best if you first [read this](https://www.shanelynn.ie/merge-join-dataframes-python-pandas-index-1/) about the way merging works (e.g. understand the venn diagrams posted there) and then you can improve your code yourself accordingly! *Or:* clean up your data manually before, sometimes there isn´t a fully automatic solution!